# Avoid checking the same condition every step in a loop in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, coding-style, conditional-statements

I am checking a condition inside a loop, and if it holds, do something.

```cpp
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    // do lots of work here
    .
    .
    .
    if (constant_condition)
        do_something(n);
}
```

The condition is independent of `n`, so it feels redundant to check it every time. I could instead do this:

```cpp
if (constant_condition)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // do lots of work here
        .
        .
        .

        do_something(n);
    }
else
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // do lots of work here
        .
        .
        .    
    }
```

This new code is more efficient, but I had to copy paste the same code in my program. Is there an efficient way to do this without repeating the same block of code?

Edit: the condition is not known at compile time, but it will be given at runtime and will not change.

Comment: Just leave the condition in.  If it is complex (more than just testing a variable), store the condition into a `bool` variable before the loop.  Branch prediction will eliminate most (if not all) of the overhead of the conditional. Don't repeat yourself ("DRY").

Comment: make a function for `// do lots of work here`, and then you don't repeat much.

Comment: When you say you have a `constant_condition`, are you talking about something that is known at compile time, or something that just doesn't change at run time?  That said, if the condition never changes the branch predictor will learn this pretty quick and it wont really cost you anything.

Comment: Why the negative votes everyone? Just trying to learn how to write a clean code. If you have suggestions to improve the question, let me know.

Comment: how to best write this is primiarily opinion based. If you worry about performance, then you best stop worrying and write for readability instead and measure the running code instead of speculating beforehand. That being said, put a `const bool constant_condition = ...` before the loop and then use that inside the loop

Comment: yea you make a function out of it, and pass the `do_something` as std::function and make it null by default. For example.

Comment: @Dimfred That does not work, because the branch would still be there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, profile to see if it matters. If it does, you have several options:

- Cache the constant outside of the loop if the compiler hasn't done so already. This is the simplest and in most cases, enough:

  ```
  const bool constant_condition = ...;
  for (...) {
     ...
     if (constant_condition) do_something(...);
  }
  ```
- If you really need to avoid the branch, a typical approach is to define an auxiliary function or a local lambda (C++11) to factor out the common blocks of code. However, this still duplicates code and, depending on the case, may not look pretty at all:

  ```
  auto main_work = [...](...) { ... };
  if (constant_condition)
      for (...) { main_work(...); }
  else
      for (...) { main_work(...); do_something(...); }
  ```
- Define a template and parametrize as needed. The compiler will typically optimize properly, so you can simply copy-paste the code. If you really want to ensure the branch is removed, you can force it specializing the template, or taking advantage of `if constexpr` (C++17) etc. However, beware of code bloat and compilation times.

  ```
  template <bool constant_condition>
  void f(...) { ... }

  if (constant_condition)
      f<true>(...);
  else
      f<false>(...);
  ```

Finally, don't forget to profile again. Sometimes, removing a branch may look good, yet be detrimental overall. This is specially true if the code changes a lot and what initially looked like a small duplication of instructions is now several memory pages full of duplicated code.

Another alternative is trying to see if the algorithm/code can be written as branchless instead; however, that isn't a general solution.

Comment: That's true to profile but it's not an answer to the question. Say it turns out there's no difference. Then OP wouldn't have any idea why

Comment: OP didn't ask "why". They asked "*Is there an efficient way to do this without repeating the same block of code?*". This answers that. But OP also claimed the second is more efficient, so I mentioned profiling, because it may not be true.

Answer (score 0):

I did not profile this code, but due to branch predictors in the CPU this definitely will have a negligible impact on code speed.

The if instruction would pass through the CPU a bunch, but the main impact on code speed when it comes to branches is parallelization, out of order instruction execution, and cache optimization being messed up, but they wont be interfered with due to the branch predictor.

Comment: The question isn't about why it's faster. It could be slower or faster, depending on stuff we don't know about the code, architecture, compiler... It's unknown code, so we cannot say much.